# Navigator SceneTransitions for popToTop

Tags: react-native

I have pushed some route using [navigator.push(route)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#push). With [configure scene props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#configurescene), I set the scene transition to  `Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid`

I would like to change the animation displayed when I use [navigator.popToTop()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#poptotop). The current animation is the `Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid`(last route animation).

Simply said, how can I change a [Navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html)'s [popToTop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#poptotop) SceneTransition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

The opposite scene transition of the last route pushed is displayed when using `popToTop`. Changing the scene transition of the last route pushed will change the popToTop animation.

For exemple, with [naviagator.replaceAtIndex(route, index, cb)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#replaceatindex), you can replace a scene transition property for the last pushed route :

```
const routes = navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
const indexToReplace = routes.length - 1;
var newRoute = routes[indexToReplace];

newRoute.sceneConfig = Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromLeft;

navigator.replaceAtIndex(newRoute, indexToReplace, () => navigator.popToTop());
```